# Calling 2 Restful Webservices simultaneously. Can mule be used?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, mule

I have two RESTful webservices 'A' and 'B'. Service 'A' is in the cloud and service 'B' is deployed in Mule. We have to hit service 'A' first to get a response that we use to call service 'B'.

To achieve this, our initial thought was to receive the request in service 'A', get the reponse from a database, then hit service 'B' and get the results back to service 'A', then return the response to client.

I do not prefer this approach as it would add dependencies between service 'A' and 'B'.

Is there any other approach for doing this? I have read that Mule could be an option. Can I create a new endpoint in Mule which would execute these steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you can use the "content enrichment" Enterprise integration pattern.

This pattern is described [here](http://www.eaipatterns.com/DataEnricher.html).

There is an article on how to do this with Mule [here](http://blogs.mulesoft.org/enrich-your-experience-orchestration-and-data-enrichment-with-mule-3-1/) and if you are using Mule then it should probably be implemented inside that.